# Using buttons to add new row to Rails table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hopefully I can explain this in a way that makes sense: In my rails app I have a table for tickets. I'm trying to make adding tickets as easy as possible for the user. So when they click '+ Ticket' a modal pops up with a list of all the employees as buttons. When they click on the button with their name, Rails should create a new ticket and fill in the :created_employee_id field:

```haml
%div.modal.fade{:id => "add_ticket", "aria-hidden" => "true", :tabindex => "-1"}
  .modal-dialog.modal-lg
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
          %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} &times;
          %span.sr-only Close
        %h4.modal-title New Ticket
      .modal-body
        .row
          .col-md-12
            %h3 Employee creating ticket:
            - Employee.where(deleted: [false, nil]).each do |employee|
              - if (employee_check(employee))
                .col-md-4
                  %button.btn.btn-default.btn-block
                    = button_to employee.name, {:controller => "tickets", :action => "create", :created_employee_id => employee.id}, :method=>:post
```

Right now, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in TicketsController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: ticket


# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:created_employee_id)
end

def load_ticketable
```

I understand this means it isn't actually creating a new ticket, so how do I get it to do that?

Here is the tickets_controller.rb relevant stuff:

```haml
  def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
  end

  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tickets, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @tickets }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private

  def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:created_employee_id)
  end
```

Comment: Is your controller receiving the `created_employee_id`?

Comment: It is listed under request parameters. So, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your controller is expecting the params dictionary to be structured like:

`{ :ticket => { :created_employee_id => 123 } }`

I believe your button is submitting data in the form:

`{ :created_employee_id => 123 }`

Try changing `ticket_params` to this:

```
def ticket_params
    params.permit(:created_employee_id)
end
```

Comment: It looks like that may have worked... now I have to change what page it redirects to.

Comment: Not necessarily, you are trying to redirect to an undefined variable `@tickets` (plural). If you want to show the new ticket (assuming you have your Ticket show action/view set up), redirect to `@ticket` (singular).

Comment: I'm actually trying to redirect to the tickets index page.

Comment: Try `redirect_to tickets_path` or `redirect_to '/tickets'`, depending on how your routes are set up.